# what is chown root:root doing?

Tags: shell-script, root, chown

I read a tutorial and was instructed to do **`chown root:root /home/mynewuser`** as part of the process to get my ssh key working with a new user i created "kevind", however it broke the path.

**What does this do?**

**How can I reset it back to default? What ever the default would be, `/`, `~` or something?**

Tutorial came from [this answer comment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-16-04-creating-new-user-and-adding-ssh-keys?answer=36900).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general: Do not execute commands from the web if you do not know exactly what they do.

**Specially by root !!**.

The command `chown root:root /home/mynewuser` is:

> **ch**anging the **own**ership to **user:group** of **/home/mynewuser**.

However, the first comment from your [linked page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-16-04-creating-new-user-and-adding-ssh-keys?answer=36900) adds an `-R` (keep reading).

Assuming the user `kevind` (using the specific name you provided) has a main group called `kevind` also created already (you can create it if needed) the command to revert the effect is:

```
chown kevind:kevind /home/kevind
```

Which must be executed as/by root to revert the ownership of root to the user `kevind`.

A more extensive change to ensure that `kevind` doesn't have some file owned by root inside his directories (security reasons) is:

```
chown -R kevind:kevind /home/kevind
```

That will **R**ecurse inside all directories and subdirectories of the given top directory. That is a safe command, there is no real reason for a user to have a file (or directory) owned by root inside his home directory.

Answer (score 1):

The command `chown root:root` changes the user and group of the specified file or directory to user `root` and group `root`. I don't know why that answer recommends setting the chowning the directory to root:root.

To partially revert the change, use the command

```
chown mynewuser /home/mynewuser
```

This will at least set the user to `mynewuser`. To find the correct group, you can use either `getent` or grep the `/etc/passwd` file for the user, if your system doesn't have `getent`.

```
getent passwd mynewuser

grep ^mynewuser: /etc/passwd
```

You will get a line similar to this:

```
mynewuser:x:<user>:<group>:...
```

To include the correct group, use this command, where `<group>` is the number from the previous line:

```
chown mynewuser:<group> /home/mynewuser
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the recursive option `-R` wasn't used, simply using the same command with  the `mynewuser` user and primary group instead of root/root will do it.  Assuming like most modern distros whatever you are using puts the new user in its own group with the same name

`chown mynewuser.mynewuser /home/mynewuser`

as root (or via `sudo`) will un-do that.

Open a new question with your ssh key issue ...

Comment: thank you for your response, I was instructed to use `chown -R mynewuser:mynewuser /home/mynewuser/` in the line above, what are the reprocussions of this?

Comment: @KevinDanikowski the `-R` makes it recursive - it will operate on that directory, and any file/directory underneath.  Since it is the home directory for that user, that is probably appropriate.  However, I wasn't sure of your end goal, and so focused on simply reversing the command that you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Additional, can you avoid adding people to your `sudo(er)` list, if you use

```
$ chown root:root /usr/local/bin/"something"
$ chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/"something"
```

At execution time, they will be able to use the "root" permissions within the boundaries of the application "something".

Comment: Your answer does not address the user's question.

Comment: Shall I delete it @Deathgrip?